# Ubuntu IPSEC/L2TP Server EAP-Authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, l2tp

I want to set up an Ubuntu VPN-server. My system is running Ubuntu Server 12.10. 
IPSec(openswan) is running fine, but on my WinXP-Client I'm only able to connect to the VPN with the domain. (MS-Chap-v2)

My goal is, to connect to the VPN-Server with EAP-Certificate authentication. (=with user-certificate on the clients instead a combination of username/password)

I already applied the [EAP-TLS-Patch for PPP](http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/ppp/) but it haven't worked for me.

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i've solved the problem.

I have used invalid certificates on my client, with self-signed certificates everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

If configurations are proper, then goto TCP/IP settings and advanced settings and General and **uncheck Use Default Gateway on Remote Network**

Comment: The problem is, that I'm not able to connect my client to the VPN if I'm using EAP-authentication